# What are Flappy Bird UI elements?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I'm making a game similar to flappy bird using Libgdx and scene2d for UI, I wanted to know what is it called these UI elements

[image: Flappy bird]

I know the 2 elements at the bottom are buttons but I' m confused on how the score is shown, what is that box that has the score and best score inside? is that just a normal texture and the score is rendered inside it? but not really together? I mean the score and the box are separate and they just make it look like that they are combined. Is there something similar to that in Libgdx and what kind of actor is that?

Comment: The scene2d documentation lists all of the different types of widgets.

Comment: Everything which appears as a texture is a texture and text is called Label , now how they are together? By using Table actor you can place them one over another and we as a developer make them look like as they are combined.